# Am receiving error myFunction not defined when loading in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript

Am receiving notification in chrome debugger that myFunction is not defined. Could greatly use some help. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to loop through a block of as long as i is less than 10.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var i;
        if (math.random > .5) i === "Heads"}
            else { i === "tails"
    };
    while (i < 100) {
        text += "<br>This Is " + i;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the line with the `if` on it. You also apparently don't know the meaning of `===`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have also seen another error in your console using the code you have provided:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`

```
if (math.random > .5) i === "Heads"}
    else { i === "tails"
  };
```

Should be:

```
if (Math.random() > .5) {
     i = "Heads";
}
else { 
    i = "tails";
};
```

Answer (score -2):

### Create the Javascript Function first and call him

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var text = "";
      var i;
      if (math.random > .5) i === "Heads"}
        else { i === "tails"
      };
    while (i < 100) {
      text += "<br>This Is " + i;
      i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

<p>Click the button to loop through a block of as long as i is less than 10.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```